# Magento display current category level, parent and grandparent

Tags: php, magento, navigation, themes

We have a magento 1.9 installation and on the left side we want to have 3 level categories to display as shown in the attached image (the breadcrumbs image is to show the levels). Currently I'm able to get the current category and his parent.

Below is the example of how I want it.

Could you help me out on this?

[image: Left navigation]

[image: Breadcrumbs]

This is the code we have so far

```
    <?php 
$level = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getLevel();
if($level > 1){                 
        echo '
            <p class="back-to-parent">
                <a href="' . $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getUrl() . '">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName() . '
            </a></p>';
    }
    else{
        //
    }
?>

<?php if ($categories = $this->getCategoriesNavMenu()): ?>
<div id="sidebar-nav" class="block sidebar-nav-left <?php echo $this->getBlockAlias() ?>">

    <button type="button" class="btn visible-xs btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar-nav-content">Meer categorie&euml;n <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <div id="sidebar-nav-content" class="collapse">
        <div class="block-content">
            <ul id="sidebar-nav-menu">
            <?php if ($this->showHome()): ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $this->getHomeClasses() ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>"><span class="category_name">Home</span></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $categories; ?>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->getConfig()->isCollapsible()): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    Codnitive = {
        expandMenu: function(parent) 
        {
            var mode = parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].getAttribute("expanded");
            (mode == 1) ? Codnitive.collapse(parent) : Codnitive.expand(parent);
        },

        expand: function(parent)
        {
            parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "block";
            parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.backgroundPosition = "right center";
            parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("expanded", "1");
        },

        collapse: function(parent)
        {
            parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display = "none";
            parent.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.backgroundPosition = "left center";
            parent.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].setAttribute("expanded", "0");
        }
    };

    //]]>
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: I've updated my question ;-)